# What is correct syntax for filtering a list on field values?

Tags: filter, view

Salvete!  I want to filter a list like this.
Now, `[othercolumn]` is supposed to be the value of the field in the `X-Field` column.  I want to see if the `X-field` column contains the text given in the `othercolumn` field.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to create calculated field based on your two columns that returns true if one of your columns is a substring of another and false otherwise. Use FIND function:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-sharepoint-services-help/examples-of-common-formulas-HA010105479.aspx

Then create list view filter based on the calculated column.

Comment: Since you recommend a calculated column, are you saying that what I want to do is not possible?  I don't really want to create another column.  I just want to do a string match on the column that already exists.  If I create another column as you say, then wouldn't that just be a string match, too?

Comment: You can not compare two columns in CAML. As a workaround I've suggested to use calculated field.

Comment: So, the view filter can only recognize plaintext?  I know it will take certain variables like [Me] and [Today].  I looked all over for a list of variables it would accept, but couldn't find one.

Comment: In queries you can use specific values, variables like [Me], [Today] and binded parameters of XLVWP or DVWP in the following way: {Parameter name}. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff630170.aspx

Comment: If I can use the binded parameters, is there no way to, within this filter, to look up the value of another field?  (sorry for being so difficult)

Comment: No, binded value will be the same for all items in the list. The best way is to use calculated column. Why don't you want to use it? It will not be visible for any user.

Comment: Because I am making a template from the library and deploying it to 100 sites.

Comment: I think you have the correct answer, even though it doesn't solve my problem, so I'm going to mark it solved.

Comment: You can add calculated field into template of the library.

Comment: Okay, Dmitry, you got me: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/52017/how-to-match-current-user-to-a-username-column-with-calculated-columns  I'll give you my vote, too.