# How to match current user to a username column?

Tags: calculated-column

I have a list view that should only show when an admin adds the person's username to an "allowed viewers" username column.  So, I am thinking to create a calculated column that compares the current-viewing user to the username in the "allowed viewers" column.  Then, I will filter the list by the result.  If it compares to true, the list item will show.  If it compares to false, it will not show.

So my question is, what do I put in the Calculated Column field to compare my "allowed viewers" column (which contains a username) to the current user?

**[waaaay later]**

Well, I've never come to a satisfactory solution to filtering a list by the current username, and [got into more trouble here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/164491/how-to-match-current-users-email-against-text-field/164492#164492).  I'm adjusting the title of my question to better reflect my intention.

How can I use a username column and filter the view by the matching current user?

Comment: Can't you just set the permission on the list? SharePoint will handle permission trimming for you.

Comment: No, because I am using the list as a template to be set on 100 sites where each site has a different group assigned with rights to manage everything but views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After having spent hours and hours trying to get columns and calculated columns and workflows to come up with some combination that might match the current user against a value in a list-view field, I finally managed to come up with something.

In the end I used a `Current User Filter`.  [The idea came from here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/119484/7452).  But here is my take on the procedure:

The List-View page is already a Web-Part Page with a list-view web-part, so I:

1. Entered Edit Mode
2. Added a `Current User Filter` - you will find this when you go to add a new web-part to the page.  It is under `Filters`.
3. Using the drop-down arrow for the `Current User Filter` web-part (in the upper corner) I used 'Create Connection' and set the list-view as the recipient and I chose which column I wanted to filter - which is a regular person field.
4. Then, in the `Current User Filter's` web-part options, there is a place where you can specify how the value is returned.  I set it to `Name`.  This way it will return a `Display Name` instead of a domain user account name (see screenshot below).

Here is an image:

[image: Options for Filter Web Part]

That's it!

**Summary**

I added a `Filter Web Part` to the Web-Part Page and *connected* it to the `List-View` and set the return value.  This works like a charm.  Now I have a list filtered to show only those items where the username column matches the currently logged in user.  And it's all `OOTB` and scriptless.

Answer (score 3):

Okay had a play and basically use "Me".

Either:

```
// Include domain name
Me

// Remove domain name
RIGHT(Me, LEN(Me) - FIND("\", Me))
```

Note:
Column names are in the format [column]

Comment: can we use calculated columns with multi-select person field ?

Comment: Yes, I have seen it done, filter the data perhaps with find? since it is stored as plain text, "Name; Name1; Name2", this part is a little fuzzy but I think it should be fine.

Comment: Uh, how do I use that to compare Me with the username value in the "allowed users" column?  The "allowed users" column will be a multi-select field, by the way.

Comment: The logic would be something like "if(FIND(ME, [column]) > 0, TRUE, FALSE)" I can't test this on my current setup however.

Comment: Ah, it says I can't use columns defined as username data types for a calculated value...

Comment: If I change the other column to a text field, it will let me add it to the calculated column, but it says I can't use "Me" in the calculated column.  I thought I read that somewhere, actually.

Comment: This should fix it for you, http://abstractspaces.wordpress.com/2008/05/19/use-today-and-me-in-calculated-column/ (I didn't test the code in a calculated column, so it didn't warn me)

Comment: That is a hack, actually.  I already tried it on my Sharepoint Enterprise 2010, but it didn't seem to work.  I'm afraid of that anyway, because I have to create a template from these columns.

Comment: Hack/Fix yadda yadda :P! Seriously, that is the only way I can work around to do what you want to do without, maybe perhaps writing something custom like a feature which will set up the permissions on all the sites for you on the lists.. That would be really complicated.

Comment: Don't you have to use brackets, as in "[Me]" ? I know that's how you do it when you filter on a user field.

Comment: Yes, I was just proposing logic, the column names are indeed in square brackets

Comment: This doesn't really work.  Read this: http://blog.pentalogic.net/2008/11/truth-about-using-today-in-calculated-columns/

Comment: This is for usernames, that blog post is about [Today] which is an updated value. Yes this will not work for values which can change. But yes it does really work you just have to know what you are doing.

Comment: In the page you've linked to, in the comments, he says it doesn't really workd: *Apparently this doesn’t work dynamically. As Bill said above, the [Today] value doesn’t change the next day, and likewise, the [Me] trick doesn’t work for the next person. *  see the Jan 16 comment.

Comment: No you misunderstand, it works in 2010 and upwards. That comment is 2007 related.

Comment: Since Calculated Formulas only recalculated on item change, [Me] in a (hacked) Formula is the same as [Modified By]. You can not use [Me] in a Formula for a reason. The [Today] hack has been debunked long long time ago, and is the same effect as using [Modified]. And square brackets or none do exactly the same, only in Column names with spaces do they matter.