# How to remove Domain Name from [ME] Calculated field and show Display Name of User

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I use [ME] in a calculated field it returns a username of \username.
Customer wants to see the user name as display name not as login name.
Would like to know whether a SharePoint formula I can use to remove the windows authentication part, I mean  the  part?

Comment: Can't you use a people picker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove domain part, you can try the following formula

```
=RIGHT([Me], LEN([Me]) - FIND("\", [Me]))
```

Comment: Chandrakanth, I think you got this from the social msdn site forum  https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/9d7853c5-23f9-4808-9a47-cf8457a0d72b/calculated-field-removing-domain-name-from-me?forum=sharepointadminlegacy and from LambertQuin's reply.I already tried this approach and tested but  it didn't work.That's why i posted this  question here.

Comment: No, got it from an existing post on stackexchange http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/52017/how-to-match-current-user-to-a-username-column-with-calculated-columns solution given by Hugh Wood. Even, I have tried it and worked too

Comment: Can you let me know how it's responding to the formula or whether it's throwing error or something else?

Comment: thanks! Its not giving me an error, but the column value- or the domain\username doesn't change to display name.

Answer (score 0):

What is your [ME] formatting?

On my Office365 environment it is:

```
i:0#.f|membership|username@domain.com
```

I have to

- Creat my own Column ME in the List/Library
- Creat a Calculated Column with Formula:

  ```
  =RIGHT([ME], LEN([ME])-FIND("membership|", [ME])-10)
  ```
- Delete the Column ME

And before I can make a change to the Formula I have to recreate my own ME column again.

@Robert, there is no need to remove spaces in the Formulas I post, SharePoint will ignore all unnecessary spaces and line breaks when saving the Formula.